# NFC with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, web-applications, nfc

Is there any JavaScript NFC Browser implementation?
I am not looking for third party APIs!

I would like to read tags from a WebApplication (website) on a mobile phone which supports NFC.

How can I implement NFC? Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668647/can-html5-access-nfc-chips-on-mobile-phones

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the near future it could be possible to use NFC directly from the browser, [check this out](https://w3c.github.io/web-nfc/)

Or, if you want more info about then you can check the [Mozilla MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_NFC_API) about this! Sounds interesting indeed

Based on this [link](https://whatwebcando.today/nfc.html), you can also check if you browser has support for NFC.

Interesting link about it: [Web NFC Community Group report](https://github.com/w3c/web-nfc/)

Answer (score 4):

You can't read tags from webApplication. Browsers does not communicate with NFC resources (it bored me too!!)
The unique way to implementing NFC features with Javascript through Android Browser is using a WebView or framework like phoneGap in a native app.

Comment: Can't I embed a JAVA file and do it from Javascript through JAVA?

Comment: I don't think so. Java applet doesn't work on android browser and you can't access to Java API from the browser. With html5, you can use GPS or some sensors but not NFC controller.

Comment: This information is outdated

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried actually tried it myself, but there is a a number of NFC plugins [1](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc),[2](https://github.com/don/phonegap-nfc-reader),[3](https://github.com/shokai/phonegap-plugin-nfc) for [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). This should allow you to use NFC in your HTML applications. See also:

- http://www.slideshare.net/m00sey/nfc-phone-gapday

Answer (score 0):

They have proprietary API that support `JavaScript` or `Java` applets connection to their `NFC` reader. API is free of charge and seems as very good alternative.

Read more at http://www.d-logic.net/nfc-rfid-reader-sdk/