# How to start a function when NFC is around with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, nfc

Hello guys I am wondering if I can use jQuery to trigger a function when NFC device is there. So for example I have an web app and instead going to put your email and password you just simply touch your NFC device registered and you're in. Does anyone has a demo or something?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9729743/560648

Comment: Given that when I search for NFC Web API [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/API/NFC_API/Using_the_NFC_API) is what shows up, I'd say you cannot do it with a regular browser. Perhaps you should consider writing mobile apps with some dedicated library like Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

An NFC transaction happens on the hardware (obviously), and at some point your software needs to be able to interface with this transaction - in other words, you need an API to access their Username/Password from the tag.

As JavaScript usually runs in the browser and most modern browsers do not have support for an NFC API, this will be very difficult for a pure web application.

At the time of writing & to the best of my knowledge Firefox/IE/Chrome, etc. do not support the W3's proposed [Web NFC API](https://w3c.github.io/web-nfc/) (and I don't know if an implementation exists) so this would not work without having your users download an OS specific app.